# Add checkedlistbox to Excel ribbon

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, excel-addins

I have created an Excel ribbon. It contains a drop down in which the name of all the sheets in the workbook are populated when you open the workbook. Now I want to select more than one sheet from the drop down list and do some operation on those sheets only. Is there any way to select multiple choices from drop down list. Checkedlistbox control is not available for Excel ribbon. This was the only way I knew to handle this scenario. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
namespace Ribbon {
    public partial class ExcelRibbon {
        List<string> Sheets = new List<string>();
        private void ExcelRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e) {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);
        }

        void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb) {
            SheetsCollection.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i < Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Sheets.Count; i++) {
                RibbonDropDownItem item = this.Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                item.Label = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Sheets[i].Name;
                SheetsCollection.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private void SheetsCollection_SelectionChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) {
            SheetsCollection.SelectedItem.Label = SheetsCollection.SelectedItem.Label + " *";  
            if(SheetsCollection.SelectedItem.Label.EndsWith("*"))
                Sheets.Add(SheetsCollection.SelectedItem.Label.Substring(0,SheetsCollection.SelectedItem.Label.LastIndexOf(" ");          
        }
    }
}
```